# Detecting Small Sound Effects In C++

Tags: c++, audio, compare, fft, detect

I'm trying to detect very small (1-3 seconds in length) sound effects, Currently im using FMod to capture the sounds (which play on another program) using the loopback technique.

Ive been researching for the passed few days, how i can compare the captured sound effect, to a database of about 50 i have stored, I know that comparing each binary byte wont work cause slight inteference will change it. The sounds are the exact audio files being captured each time.. So the characteristcs should be almost dead on everytime.

I cant use any fingerprinting libarys which are already out there as they require to record at least 10-90 seconds of the audio.

As the sounds are so small, and in small number, i guess one of you gurus out there know a simple solution, I wanted to try and use FFT and compare some of the frequency's etc, but cant get the Kiss FFT libary working as there is absoloutly no DOCS.

Also ive just created a function to split the channels. Here

```
int SeperateChannels(FMOD::Sound *sound)
{
    byte *ptr1, *ptr2;
    unsigned int lenbytes, len1, len2;

    sound->getLength(&lenbytes, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_PCMBYTES);
    sound->lock(0, lenbytes, (void**)&ptr1, (void**)&ptr2, &len1, &len2);

    byte *bufferLeft  = new byte[(lenbytes/2)];
    byte *bufferRight = new byte[(lenbytes/2)];

    for(int i = 0; i < lenbytes; i += 4)
    {
        bufferLeft[i]   = ptr1[i];
        bufferLeft[i+1] = ptr1[i+1];

        bufferRight[i]   = ptr1[i+2];
        bufferRight[i+1] = ptr1[i+3];
    }

    // Kiss FFT????

    return 1;
}
```

Any help is greatly appriciated.
-Que

Comment: How much memory does 2-3sec sound data consume??

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It seems like it's a problem of matching audio features. Given that there's some concern over noise in the samples, I've got a strong feeling that a good solution would be relatively complex, involving some manner of machine learning and audio pattern matching. I've only done CompVis, so I dunno what sort of things they do in the audio world, but I'd imagine them to be similar... I do feel like the 'question' is all over the place, however (likely a shared sentiment).

Comment: I agree, it is unclear what the question is. To use any spectral based method you need to *at least* get an FFT working.

Comment: The question does not specify whether there are performance or latency requirements. Does the recognition have to happen instantly?

Comment: In keeping with the "KISS" theme, there is a single README file that comes with kissfft. That file, if it were actually read, would answer most of the questions people continually ask.  It does not, however, teach you how to program or describe how to use an FFT to accomplish specific tasks.

Comment: Regarding using "fingerprinting libarys which are already out there" have you evaluated this one: https://www.samplesumo.com/percussive-sound-recognition

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is to determine which of a pre-defined set of sounds has been recorded then I can think of two options: "compare" the recording to all of the sounds in your database, or perform a "lookup" based on general characteristics of the sound (usually called "descriptors" in the audio analysis literature). For descriptors I'm thinking of things like [spectral centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_centroid).

For the "compare" case you could either do this in the time domain using [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function), or in the frequency domain by computing a spectral magnitude difference. For time domain comparison you need to perform the correlation at multiple offsets since you don't know where the sound starts. For the frequency domain case you need to convert the raw FFT data into some kind of spectral envelope -- e.g. take the average of the magnitude spectrum of a set of (windowed) overlapping frames.

For the "lookup" case you would compute a set of descriptors, compute them on your corpus and on your candidate input, and then look up the element of the corpus that is closest to the descriptor you computed for the input. You can also do this over a sequence of frames: perform the same kind of correlation analysis you would have done for time-domain "compare" case, but instead of computing the difference of each sample, you compute the difference for each descriptor -- this will work better for comparing evolving sounds than just using a single descriptor.

If you intend to use an FFT you will need to work out no only how to apply the FFT, but also how to compute magnitude spectra and have some idea about the data structures you're dealing with. Getting a result requires a number of steps beyond just performing the FFT. There are a bunch of ways the matching can be optimised, especially if your sound set is fixed (I'm thinking of group testing approaches for example).

For a simpler approach you could look into the way [DTMF touch tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) decoding is done. By performing a pre-analysis of your source sounds you might be able to determine a set of non-overlapping frequencies that can be used to fingerprint each sound.

In all cases I'd do this in mono by summing left and right channels. Stereo won't give you much unless you're sure the input has the same panning as the output.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah basically thats what i need, is something suffcient enough to compare the recorded sound effect to a database/dir of about 50 other sounds; The fingerprinting is also a great way to go, but i cant get this damn Kiss FFT working, theres no documentation, so maybe best if i switch to another fft lib.

Comment: @qZanity try [ooura](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html). FFTW is the other obvious option.